# SSRS Date Picker

Tags: date, reporting-services, parameters, formatting

Is there a way to "grey out" dates that are not deemed available from the date picker calendar parameter?  I realize you can limit the available dates by using a drop down parameter, but it would be nice to have this extended to the date picker parameter.

Thanks,
Kirstie Jo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible(As far as I know) to control how `SSRS` handles user entry of `date/time` values in parameters. If there is a need to restrict to date (or time) only or do cross-field validation then you need to implement your own front-end.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my Q.  I can't vote it up, because I don't have enough points!  New to StackOverflow :)